# Unit tangent bundle and connection map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I conjecture that

$\xi \in T_{x,v} T^{1}M$ if only if  $\langle K_{x,v}(\xi), v \rangle = 0$

with $K: TTM \to TM$ the connection map is given by $K_{x,v}(\xi) =\frac{D_{h}V}{dt}(0)$ where $V$ is some curve in $TM$ such that $V(0)=(x,v)$ and $V'(0)=\frac{dV}{dt}(0) =\xi$.

where $T^{1}M= UTM =$ the unit tangent bundle.

I have no idea how to prove it.

Hints or solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: I assume that by $T^1M$ you mean the unit tangent bundle for the Riemannian manifold $M$. You have not correctly defined $K_{x,v}(\xi)$. You mean to take $V'(0)=\xi$ and $K_{x,v}(\xi)$ the horizontal component of $V'(0)$ with respect to the connection?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\g#1#2{\left\langle #1 , #2 \right\rangle}$The unit tangent bundle is the submanifold of $TM$ defined as the regular level set  $T^1 M = f^{-1}(1)$ of the smooth function $f : TM \to \mathbb R : v \mapsto \g{v}{v};$ so its tangent space $T_{x,v} T^1 M$ is the kernel of $df|_{x,v}$. Given an arbitrary $\xi \in T_{x,v} TM,$ let $V : (-\epsilon , \epsilon) \to TM$ be a curve with $V'(0) = \xi$ and compute using the chain rule and metric-compatibility $$df|_{x,v} (\xi) = \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}(f \circ V)= 2\g{\frac{DV}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}}{v} = 2\g{K_{x,v}(\xi)}{v}.$$ Thus the kernel is exactly the subspace you conjecture.